# Can anyone identify this 1900 Russian or Cossack uniform?

Tags: identification, russia, uniform

This is a picture of my grandmother and her parents.

[image: Image of my grandmother and her parents]

Comment: You'd better to ask this question here https://forum.vgd.ru/148/104756/

Comment: Wish it were just slightly clearer. That _looks_ like an imperial shashka, but can't quite see the 'eye' or beak, hidden in shadows. Wish I had my dad's copy of Stella and Rose's book.